# AspectJ and Spring: Exclude @After method execution when method throws an exception

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

I have and Aspect in spring based on aspectJ:

```
@After("execution(* ...)
public void stopTotalTimerAndMarkSucess(JoinPoint joinPoint) {...}

@AfterThrowing("execution(* c ..)
public void markError(JoinPoint joinPoint) {...}
```

I need to exclude @After execution when my under method throws and exception.
Now when a method throws an exception are executed both (@After and @AfterThrowing).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need @AfterReturning annotation rather than @After.

@AfterReturning:

> After returning advice runs when a matched method execution returns
>   normally. It is declared using the @AfterReturning annotation (...)

@After:

> After (finally) advice runs however a matched method execution exits.
>   It is declared using the @After annotation. After advice must be
>   prepared to handle both normal and exception return conditions. It is
>   typically used for releasing resources, etc.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html

Comment: just a quick note, if for some reason you decide to do it in one method, you could use @Around.